# How to run a script from batch file

Tags: javascript, batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to run a script to update all the javascript files which has a header XYZ and if the header is present inside any number of the file, then rename all the files as *.js.exclude.

I was able to write a command line script which is working fine from CMD if i am running the command on the folder path.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /s /m "XYZ" *.js') do ECHO ren "%a" "%%~nxa.exclude"
```

Now I need to run this script as a tool eg: a *.bat file. How will I accomplish this.

I tried adding cd <>folder path and then the above script. But it is not working. Also the cmd window is getting closed regardless of the PAUSE. 
Please advice

Comment: You can create .bat files in notepad and save it as an .bat, double click it to make it run. Normally if you put "call" before calling something in cmd it does not close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Use double prefix "%%" before variables in batch files.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /s /m "XYZ" *.js') do ECHO ren "%%a" "%%~nxa.exclude"
```